# How do I keep an S-Corporation open when it has no revenues

Tags: united-states, business, s-corporation

I have an S-Corporation using which I used to do consulting work a few years back. Now, the revenues from that corporation has come down to zero. I hate to close it down in case I want to consult again. For the whole of 2011, I have been filing zero revenue tax returns to various government agencies. I would like to stop that as well but still keep the corp itself open with the option to restart everything in the future if so desired. How do I go about doing this? The S-corporation is registered in Illinois. I do not mind paying the yearly corporate filing fee of $100.00 to keep it open. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no net income or loss, you can usually get away without filing a tax return.  In Illinois, the standard is:

> Filing Requirements
>   You must file Form IL-1120 if you are a corporation that
>   has net income or loss as defined under the IITA; or
>   is qualified to do business in the state of Illinois and is required to file a federal income tax return (regardless of net income or loss).
>   http://tax.illinois.gov/Businesses/TaxInformation/Income/corporate.htm

Just keep your filing fee and any business licenses up to date, paying those fees personally and not out of business money (that would make for a net loss and trigger needing a tax return).  Frankly, with how easy it is to register a new corp, especially an LLC which has many simplicity advantages from an S-corp in certain cases, you might still be better off shutting it down until that time.

Comment: I disagree: it's best to avoid mixing personal and corporate money. The corporation should pay its own fees.

Comment: Yes, completely agree, it is best to avoid whenever possible.  But, in that event, his goal won't be achieved.  That is why I state that shutting it down and then starting a new entity might be easier.  Keeping a non-running corporation afloat provides little benefit and lots of silly little complications like the one that paying to keep it afloat will beget activity to require more reporting, etc.